Flow subscribe/collect on Android is catch in 2 fragments
I am building an app and I am using Flow and State.
I have 2 fragments A and B. They are never displayed at the same time.
In each fragment I am observing the change of state as below:
private fun subscribeToState() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.uiState.apply {
            flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
            collect { state ->
                when (state) {
                    Complete -> {
                        // DO SOMETHING
                    }

                    Loading -> {
                        // DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

So the subscribeToState is on both FragmentA and FragmentB. When FragmentB is loaded, FragmentA is stopped.
The ViewModel is defining the flow as below:
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Empty)
val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState

When I trigger an action from FragmentB there is a couple of processing happening in the view model and when the procession is done, the view model does _uiState.value = Complete but in my case, I am still in FragmentB but the state event using flow is caught in FragmentA even if FragmentA is stopped.
Any idea how to make sure any state is catch by the proper fragment?

Since you are using STARTED as the lifecycle state you did confirm that onStop is being called in the fragment when you go to Fragment B?

@tyczj yes I did see the onStop
